# GPUImage Crop to Detected Corners

Tags: ios, gpuimage, edge-detection

I'm working on an iOS app that takes a picture of a piece of paper and detects it as separate from the background.

I've begun working with Brad Larson's GPUImage, and I'm having some success, but not a lot.

I can take a picture and apply a filter and see that corners are returned/found, but I can't get the crosshairs generator to actually do anything in my app (example apps seem to work ok, though) and I don't know how to do anything with the "corners" that are detected.

Ideally, I'd like to get the corners, do some math to find the largest actual rectangle (which I'm going to assume is my paper) and then crop the image to that rectangle.

Has anyone done anything like this?

Comment: Are you using `-forceProcessingAtSize:` to set the correct size for the crosshair generator? Otherwise, it doesn't know what image size to use when creating the crosshairs. Beyond that, the corners that are returned should be in a normalized 0..1 coordinate space, so you should be able to generate a size-independent crop out of that. You may have to handle rotation and other transformations independently in order to straighten your piece of paper, though.

Comment: @mbm29414 Did you ever find a good way to detect corners? Do you have code you are willing to share?